# Not able to trigger JiraTestResultReporter plugin on Post Build Action in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I want to log defects automatic on jira whenever any test case gets fail.for that i have used JiraTesttResultReport plugin.i have successfully able to create my report.xml file.but i got below errors:

```
 Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
[JiraTestResultReporter] [INFO] Examining test results...
ERROR: Publisher JiraTestResultReporter.JiraReporter aborted due to exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getTestResultAction()Lhudson/tasks/test/AbstractTestResultAction;
    at JiraTestResultReporter.JiraReporter.perform(JiraReporter.java:105)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
```

Answer (score 0):

On what version of Jenkins are you working?
**JiraTestResultReporter does not work on Jenkins 1.577+**
It's a known [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25140)

A workaround is to build and install a snapshot of the plugin.

Comment: so how can we use this plugin on Jenkins 1.577+